# msxsl:node-set strange behaviour

Tags: .net, xslt

I am new to the xslt and is getting the following behavior. I am getting different result when trying to count the items using node-set that has a pattern condition on it. The result change depending if I cast the value of the condition into a string or not as below. Can some expert help explain what cause this behavior.

```
 <xsl:for-each ....

  //there is two area that why we need the position()=1
     <xsl:variable name="checkLocation" select="area[position()=1]" />
```

Scenario A - wrong result

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(msxsl:node-set($allItems)//item[area[position()=1] = $checkLocation])"/>   will show 10
```

Scenario B - correct result after casting the left condition into a string

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(msxsl:node-set($allItems)//item[string(area[position()=1]) = $checkLocation])"/>    will show show 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any obvious reason for this: which probably means that the explanation lies somewhere in the part of the code that you haven't shown us. Can you post a complete working sample that demonstrates the problem, ideally without using msxsl:node-set()?